# Authentication for Logic Apps that scale

Tags: authentication, azure-logic-apps

I currently have a logic app whose connector uses PAT tokens and this is not scalable. Looking at something like a service account or managed identities but having reviewed documentation, it is not entirely clear what to use.

Answer (score 0):

For few of the connectors you can use either service principle or managed identity(i.e.. Azure Resource Manager) but currently for some Connectors (i.e.. storage account, outlook) you need to use Personal Access Token only as it is not supported and is still under preview. You can check more on it from [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/263744/trouble-connecting-to-monitor-log-in-logic-app.html).

Here is a [BLOG](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/azure-logic-apps-authenticate-with-managed-identity-for-azure-ad/ba-p/2066254) that you can follow for Managed Identity for a few Connectors.

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you have documentation on using a service account with Logic Apps?

Comment: Here is the MS docs that explain how you can get the service principle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-authenticate-service-principal-powershell

Comment: You just need to give the obtained Client ID, Client Secret and Tenant Id while authenticating with service principle